# ShowAllData excel macro to clear table from filters gives error 9 out of script

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button that copy/paste some columns from a source table to a new table/sheet, and this works ok, except when the source table is filtered. If somehow I left some filters, it won't copy all data :(

I've tried several combinations of "ShowAllData" but still all of them fail with the same error '9' OutOfScript... here's mi whole code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim row_last As Long
    Dim range_src As String
    Dim cols_src As Variant

    cols_src = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "I", "R", "S", "T", "U")
    Sheets("TMP").Cells.Clear

    With Sheets("Validation by rules")
        ' Set lo = .ListObjects(1)
        ' lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        ' Sheets("Validation by rules").ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        ' ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        row_last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(cols_src) To UBound(cols_src)
            ' MsgBox .Cells(1, cols_src(i))
            .Range(.Cells(1, cols_src(i)), .Cells(row_last, cols_src(i))).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TMP").Cells(1, i + 1)
        Next i
    End With
    MsgBox CStr(row_last) & " records copied"
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Any hints appreaciated, as to what I'm doing wrong... Thanks!

Comment: I like to use .showalldata, but it errors out whenever the sheet happens to have no filters working right now.  So what I do is to use three lines for showalldata:    on error resume next / .showalldata / on error goto 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check whether the autofilter is display using the ShowAutoFilter property of the ListObject object, and then show all of the data, if it's in filter mode.

```
Dim lo As ListObject

With Sheets("Validation by rules")
    Set lo = .ListObjects(1)
    With lo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            With .AutoFilter
                 If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
            End With
        End If
    End With
    'etc
    '
    '
    '
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @Domenic.  I copied this code, but it fails with same message (9) at the first line
    Set lo = .ListObjects(1)
       With lo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            With .AutoFilter
                If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
            End With
        End If
    End With

Comment: It suggests that your sheet named "Validation by rules" does not contain a Table.  Do you in fact have a Table, one that was created via `Ribbon > Insert > Tables > Table`?

Comment: Thanks @Domenic. I do have a table, but created from Home->Format as Table, so I can sort/filter in just one click :) I guess this is just "formatting" and not "table" then??? :( If that's so... maybe using Range then?

Comment: Doing so converts it to a table as well.  Can you please confirm which lines causes the error, and which error it is?

Comment: With Sheets("Validation by rules")
    Set table01 = .ListObjects(1)
     lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    With lo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            With .AutoFilter
                If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
            End With
        End If
    End With

Comment: Sorry.. don't know why code is not formatted in the previous post... anyway, error is on the "Set table01...." and error is 9 OutOfScript

Comment: If you're getting a subscript out of range error when trying to assign the first listobject to your variable, as you are trying to do in your code, then no listobject exists.  If you select a cell within your table, does the `Table Tools` tab appear?

Comment: Nope :( as I said, I "created" this object (don't wanna say "table" now) by selecting a range and then clicking on "Format as a table" under Home... but I do get filters on the top row as result...

Comment: The code should work if the workbook containing your sheet named "Validation by rules" is the active workbook, and that sheet contains a Table/ListObject.  I've edited my post to make it clear as to how you should amend your code.

Comment: Thanks again... I tried a few things... created a new sheet, inserted a table, MsgBox the result of ListObjects.Count, and it was 1, but for the sheet with my "table" created from "Format as Table" it's 0... so I just don't have a table :( I selected my "range" and Inserted a table on it, and it worked so thanks! Now, I don't like the format of that insert (one row white, one row light blue, etc.), so I need to figure out how to insert a boring table (all rows with no colors).. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: It's interesting that your original table wasn't being recognized.  I had tested `Format as Table` with both Excel 2007 and 2016 and it worked.  In any case, to remove the formatting `TableTools > Design > Table Styles > None`.

Answer (score 1):

you could simplify the copy/paste operation as follows

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim range_src As String

    Sheets("TMP").Cells.Clear
    With Sheets("Validation by rules")
        '.ShowAllData ' uncomment tgis line to copy/paste all data
        Intersect(.Range("A:D, I:I, R:U"), .Rows(1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TMP").Cells(1, 1)
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```